# Configuring Multiple Persistence Units In JPA In Same XML File

Tags: spring, jpa

I have two databases A,B.I have a table called asample in database A and bsample in database B. Now I want to transfer the data from bsample table of B database to asample table of A database. For this I have to use two persistence units in my persistence.xml file. I am using JPA, Spring. I am new to jpa. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this.

If I use the below mentioned code I am getting this exception:

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring-context/dao-DB1.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mediationEntityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring-context/dao-DB2.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: DB2] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mediationEntityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring-context/dao-DB2.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: DB2] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:275)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: DB2] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 41 more
```

Iplaced the two persistence units in my persistence.xml file and I have two dao files as dao-DB1.xml, dao-DB2.xml there I am configuring the EntityManager as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Spring offers the PersistenceUnitManager to act as a central repository and avoid the (potentially expensive) persistence units discovery process . The default implementation allows multiple locations to be specified .

```
<bean id="pum" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
  <property name="persistenceXmlLocation">
    <list>
     <value>org/springframework/orm/jpa/domain/persistence-multi.xml</value>
     <value>classpath:/my/package/**/custom-persistence.xml</value>
     <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
    </list>
  </property>

</bean>

<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="pum"/>
</bean>
```

Source - [Spring orm jpa](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html#orm-jpa)

Comment: Worked like a charm after switching 'persistenceXmlLocation' with 'persistenceXmlLocations'

Answer (score 3):

Example `persistence.xml` with two datasources, in this case both Oracle databases, using hibernate as the JPA provider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="DB1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:port:sid"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="username"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="DB2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <!-- same as above, different properties -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

If you want to configure the persistence units via spring, you can do:

```
<bean id="DB1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:port:sid"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>

<bean id="DB2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <!-- same as above, different properties --> 
</bean>

<bean id="DB1entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="DB1-unit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="DB1"/>
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="DB2entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="DB2-unit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="DB2"/>
    <!-- same as above -->
</bean>
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you rather configure your jpa via spring rather than in the persistence xml if you're wanting to have to persistence units.

Comment: Hi Thanks alot for giving the reply.I am using your code but i have a doubt while i am reading in google so many are using the JpaTemplate and TransactionManager.But i didnt understand that what is the use of using those.Is it required to use those in my xml file.If required to use can you tell me how to use those for my two databases.

Comment: The code shows two alternative ways to configure two datasources and persistence units. The first is done exclusively in `persistence.xml`, the other via spring. In a DAO, you can use the spring `@PersistenceContext` annotation to inject the entity manager associated with a specific persistence unit. You can then execute queries via that entity manager. If you have different question, you should try to write a clearer question, and be more specific than "Can anyone tell me how can i achieve this."

Comment: I placed the two persistence units in my persistence.xml file and i am using two dao files as dao-DB1.xml and dao-DB2.xml.I am writing the code for the corresponding EntityManagerFactory in the respective xml files.When i run the application it is giving that javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: ra_db_mediation_PU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory.If you want the full stack trace i will edit the post.

Comment: SO is not a general-purpose 'help me fix my project' site; if you need help with a another aspect of your project, narrow down the scope and ask a new question. Your original question (as I read it) was "how can I specify two datasources in persistence.xml", which has been answered.